# Angular 6 + rxjs - Mapped HTTP Response not returning response;

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I have the following http POST trying to be returned to another function:

```
return this.http.post(ENDPOINT_URL + 'MY-JWT-VALIDATION' + token, {observe: 'response'}, {headers: headers})
 .pipe(map( (res) => { return res; } ));
```

However, what I'm getting from the return is an Observable object with all that data vs. the actual response of the call.  I've tried changing from `map` to `tap` to `subscribe` and everything.

Google seems to infer I'm doing this properly, but for some reason I can't get a response back.. even if I just return a static string.

Been stuck at this for a hour.  My other http.post calls seem to be working fine and carry this same logic though I pass them through a function first.

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: so, the return type of that snippet is `Observable<Object>`, right? and what do you expect? `Observable<HttpResponse<Object>>`? In not sure of what you mean with _an Observable object with all that data vs. the actual response of the call_

Comment: Well, if you are observing the response `{observe: 'response'}` of course you will receive all the data from the response ;) Remove that to get just the data.

Comment: @AJT_82 cant be the case, as the 3rd argument are the options of the request. The default observe is applied.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo - The return type (from help toolbars) inside my code says `Observable<string>`, but it is an object of `Observable<object>` when I print it out.  I am expecting to receive the actual JSON response from the server as with all my other `http.post` requests.  That JSON should resemble what I get from my REST API testing program such as: `{
"code": "jwt_auth_no_auth_header",
"message": "Authorization header not found.",
"data": {
"status": 403
}
}`
(so yes, I believe `Observable<HttpResponse<Object>>` is correct and what I need from quickly checking the docs)

Comment: @Jota.Toledo You are correct, I looked too hasty and just focused on the `{observe: 'response'}` :D

Comment: Is `{observe: 'response'}` really meant to be your body for the request?

Comment: @AJT_82 - Nope!  I just put that in from a tutorial I saw as I assumed it would tell this post request to throw me back the response rather than the Observable object I am getting.

I can remove it and get the same thing: `this.http.post(ENDPOINT_URL + 'jwt-auth/v1/token/validate?token=' + token, {}, {headers: headers})
     .pipe(map(res => JSON.stringify(res) ));`.

I am expecting to get the JSON response back from my `.pipe(map..` scenario,  and should be able to put `res => { return 'test' }` in there and get back the <string> 'test', no?  I'm not getting back what I think I should be

Comment: Could you just for clarity's sake also add the component code for this as well. Seems a bit odd to me this :)

Comment: @AJT_82 - Added to the bottom of the original for you; it is just a single Service for authentication.  The function we are looking at is `validateAuthToken` and it is being passed a token from where it is called.  JSON is literally just going to return either a success if the token is valid or a failure if not, but I can't get that JSON response returned.

Comment: well that explains it, you are not subscribing to the observable you get, but setting it directly to storage. You need to subscribe.

Comment: @AJT_82 - I think you are looking at the wrong function?  Everything else here works but the `validateAuthToken` function which only returns.

Comment: I'm maybe getting tired here :D But where is the code which calls this `validateAuthToken`? That was what I meant to ask for when I asked for the component code :) The part where you console log and get that output you are showing.

Comment: @AJT_82 - It's just a single line setting that return to a variable on a page so I can console.log() and print it out on the HTML: `this.test = this.authenticationService.validateAuthToken(localStorage.getItem('jwt_token'));` .  The token gets passed through successfully.

Comment: So you are printing `test`? Still, that **is** an observable, so expected output in that case.

Comment: @AJT_82 - I am just printing `test`!  If that's expected, then how do I get the actual response of my http.post request?  I need the http POST's response.

Comment: You need to **subscribe** :)

Comment: `this.authenticationService.validateAuthToken(localStorage.getItem('jwt_token')).subscribe(data => this.test = data)`

Comment: @AJT_82 - Like such? `this.authenticationService.validateAuthToken(localStorage.getItem('jwt_token')).subscribe( data => this.test = data );`

Comment: @AJT_82 - That looks like it; thank you so much bud!  I'm not sure why I didn't know that was the place to do it--I kept trying to subscribe on the http.post side.

Really appreciate you taking all the time to help through my ignorance.

Success!: `{"code":"jwt_auth_valid_token","data":{"status":200}}` .  Think I need to go re-read on Observables yet again.

Comment: Yes, well if you were trying to subscribe in the service (if you mean that with `trying to subscribe on the http.post side`) would mean that you would then return a **subscription**. Just remember that your data is inside the subscribe block :)

Comment: No problem, glad we got it sorted out. Yes, dig into documentation to really get a good grip on the things! Good luck and happy coding! :)

Comment: @AJT_82 - Yup, that is correct--and I did get a `subscription` when trying that, which is why I took it back off. =)  Again, thank you for the help and tips!  DM me your PayPal info or something; would love to buy you a coffee in thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Answer solved by @AJT_82 in the comments.

Issue wasn't with the line of the function I posted, but rather my call to the function on another page--where I did not **subscribe**.

My original `this.test = this.authenticationService.validateAuthToken(localStorage.getItem('jwt_token'));`

Needed to `subscribe` and actually get the data to be assigned.. instead of just keeping trying to assign the Observable back to my `this.test` variable like a doofus: `this.authenticationService.validateAuthToken(localStorage.getItem('jwt_token')).subscribe( data => this.test = data );`

Comment: Also forgot to mention that... if you do not want to use `subscribe()` you can also use the `async` pipe in template, but you'll run into that when digging deeper in the mysteries of Angular :) I prefer subscribing though and never found a liking for the async pipe. But that is my personal opinion ;) Many others like it!

Comment: Since I can't see your code, I don't know exactly what is going on, but I guess it has to do with the fact that this is asynchronous. This should in that case help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2

Comment: @AJT_82 - Ack; sorry for pulling you back--I managed to figure it out just before you posted =)  Thanks again!  I will leave you alone now! haha; enjoy your evening!